# Twitter on iOS 5: OAServiceTicket is no good

Tags: iphone, twitter, ios5

i am using TwitterEngine and OAuthSignInViewController.
The problem is that i'm getting access token that is not good.
The OAServiceTicket is not with the right data.
The thing is that on 4.3 it works fine, but on 5 is bad.

What the difference? 
How to fix it?

Tnx